# Call angularJS function on page load from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am very New to AngularJS and I have an web Application that calls an ng-click when a button is clicked. I would like to add code to call this function on page load.

[image]

This is the where the function is called in the code. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1):

When element is loaded you can fire ng-init

```
<div ng-init="zoom.fit()">
  some code
</div>
```

[ng-init documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your controller

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
  $scope.zoo.fit();
});
```

Comment: What if I dont know where the controller is and the only way I can call this is from javascript?